# Appending Data to a List from dictionary search Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, append

Hi all firstly here is my code:

```
import os

rootdir= 'C:\Documents and Settings\Guest\My Documents\SC\Actual work\Part2\New Folder'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
  for file in files:
    f=open(file,'rU')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for line in lines:
        if "2002" in line:
            print line
```

This achieves my attended result of searching all the files in the directory and printing only lines that match 2002. This then just outputs them into a long list of 2002 values in the shell.

What I would like to know is there a way to associate each data to its file to be called later. I.e can I add an append/extend statement somewhere in the loop so that it associates each data to its file. I.e the output I want is:

```
datafile("name") = [list of all 2002 matches] 
datafile("name2") = [list of all 2002 matches in file 2]
```

So that I can call these lists later. I want to do it such that in the code it searches and creates the list on the fly. My new code is below however it doesnt group all the first file data into one list it just prints each match into a list.

```
rootdir= 'C:\Documents and Settings\Guest\My Documents\SC\Actual work\Part2\New Folder'


for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
 for file in files:
    f=open(file,'rU')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for line in lines:
        newlist=[]
        if "2011" in line:
            x= newlist.append(line)
            print newlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use a dictionary.

```
datafile = {}

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
  for file in files:
   f=open(file,'rU')
   lines = f.readlines()
   f.close()
   newlist=[]
   for line in lines:           
       if "2011" in line:
           x= newlist.append(line)
           print newlist
   datafile[file] = newlist


print datafile  # this prints out every file name, and the corresponding list of matches (if any).
```

To get the data you want, do this:

```
print datafile["filename"]
```

To print your filenames, use a loop:

```
for f in datafile:
    print f, datafile[f][:1]
```

Comment: Hmmm not really this didnt achieve my result. It just added the data to one big list. Not an individual list containing each name and its values. I was after. Filename= [all 2011 data for first file], filename2 = [all data for second file]

Comment: Not really sure what more you want...  Have you tried printing datafile?

Comment: Yes that looks better. I can access the data by typing the name. Is there a way to call all the names via a loop. I.e can I get the filenames via print datafile without having to type in each value

Comment: can you also print a single value from these lists

Comment: Thanks @jh314. Is it possible then to strip out only just one value from it. I.e in each string there is a word can I take this out using the same code or do I need a new one